# maximum partition size for Windows 7 Embedded 32-bits

Tags: windows-7, partition

This question has been asked before, but a clear answer was never provided, I also tried to google this simple question, but can't get a clear answer.

Does anyone here knows the answer to this question, just a simple answer, no need for a background or history lessons:

Can Windows 7 (32-bit) support partitions larger than 2-TB?
Note: Not 64-bits

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it depends on the format you are using.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/what-is-the-biggest-hard-disk-size-that-can-used/0947610f-0dc1-4ef1-803c-3f8110356486